# Lamp server permission denied while uploading files

Tags: apache

I installed Apache server,php and mysql servers in order on ubuntu.
But after restarting apache server,when i tried to upload some files in www, i cant upload because of permission issues.
when i  tried to change the permission of folder by typing on terminal :

```
chown -R <user>  /var/www
```

and

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

it said :  Operation not permitted

what can i do about this?thanks.

Comment: http://serverfault.com is better suited for server configuration questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sudo those commands, e.g.
sudo chmod -R 755 directory

Also, make sure /var/www is owned by www-data user/group.